# Add Suffix To Controller Classes In Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been through the router class and have not found where the controller classes are loaded.

What I've found is that often controller class names will make sense having the same name as a model for instance I might have a controller called user as well as a model called user where the controller has basic crud functions built into it.

The problem is that If I call upon the User model within the User controller I cannot re-declare the class.

What I propose is to have the controller name be User_Controller so as not to re-declare the user model.

Does anyone have any idea how this or perhaps a better solution can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

I do not quiet understand your question perhaps you are looking for "naming" conventions or use of `load model` 2nd parameter. Please see example below.

**controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model', 'user');
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->user->get(); //calls user_model method get();
    }

}

/* End of file user.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/user.php */
```

**model**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User_model extends CI_Model {

    function get() {
        return 1; //all database calls etc..
    }

    function complexFunction() {
        $this->get(); //calls User_model get()
        return 1;
    }

}

/* End of file user_model.php */
/* Location: ./application/models/user_model.php */
```

Comment: If you are at all familiar with mage to for example.. all controllers follow this naming convention namespace_module_controller_path_to_file. This makes it very unlikely to have two classes with the same name. What I would like to do is when a model is loaded in the manner described above assume that the path is the same but at instantiation suffix the class name with _controller.